# Creating scheduled jobs (polling) with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, cron, scheduled-tasks, polling

in my NodeJS app i need to send requests every 2-3 seconds to the third-party service. I have database with objects that contains URL to request and when response is coming i link this response with my object.

Now it's like:

```
// Getting objects from DB and calling ask function
objectsFromDB.find(function(err, data){
    if(!err){         
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          var object = data[i];
          // Calling ask function
          startAsking(object);                    
      }    
    }
});

// Start asking objects ...
function startAsking(object){
  var intervalId = setInterval(function(){
      console.log("Asking " + object.name);
      // ...
      // Processing and linking response with object
  }, config.INTERVAL);
 arrayOfIntervals.push(intervalId);
};
```

So, now i need to stop the job for **one of the objects**. How can i do this ?
I see that i can save intervalId but what happens if this intervalId is not mutch with the object ?

Also i see many libraries like:

- [Agenda](https://www.npmjs.com/package/agenda)
- [nschedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nschedule)
- [node-cron](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron)

But i think that all of this libraries is oriented to schedule jobs whit large interval, and i don't know how to stop one of the jobs.